# How to prevent matrix from accessing unnallowed values

Tags: c, for-loop, matrix

Hello I created a random 6x6 matrix `int S[6][6]` and the issue is that when I try to access the value of an unexisting square like `S[6][-1]` square it should return 0 but instead it returns the `S[5][5]` square. if I try dynamic allocation,I get 0x0005 seg fault.

```
2  1  2  1  2  1
2  1  1  2  1  1
2  2  1  1  2  1
1  2  1  1  1  2
1  2  2  2  1  1
1  1  1  2  2  2        //S[0][6] = S[1][0]
```

is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably implement a function for doing that. It could look like this:

```
int matrix_get_value(int row, int column) {
    if(row < 0 || row >= 6 || column < 0 || column >= 6)
        return 0;
    return matrix[row][column];
}
```

It could also be done in a more dynamic way by passing the matrix as a function  parameter

```
int matrix_get_value(int **matrix, int size_rows, int size_columns, int row, int column) {
    if(row < 0 || row >= size_rows || column < 0 || column >= size_columns)
        return 0;
    return matrix[row][column];
}
```

In this solution the matrix is passed to the function as a double pointer (pointer to pointer), but this can be done in other ways too.

Comment: Thank you, do I need to declare the matrix as public in the first code?

Comment: In c there is no public keyword, but the matrix needs to be global (declared outside any functions).  Using global variables is often considered bad and therefore the second version is better in most cases.